# Thunderbird email: cloning an account

Tags: email, thunderbird, clone, profile

I'm running `Thunderbird` 78.14.0 under Linux.

In a given `Thunderbird` profile, I have several email accounts, all of which are using IMAP. I want to "clone" one of these accounts, as follows ...

Suppose that one of the accounts is called "email". I would like to create another account that runs under the same `Thunderbird` profile, and I'd call it "newemail", for example. I'd like it to end up having all of the exact, same settings as the existing "email" account. I'd then want to go into the "newemail" account and make a few minor changes to the settings, although almost all of these settings will be the same as those under the "email" account.

I know I can do this by creating the "newemail" account and manually setting all of its attributes, one by one, to be the same as those in the "email" account. I also know I could accomplish this by messing with `prefs.js` or perhaps one or more of the other `Thunderbird` config files. However, I'm wondering if there might be some sort of utility, tool, or add-on which I could use to "clone" an existing account in the way I described.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.